# What is the simplest way to display raster image in R?

Tags: r

I'm working with TIFF images in R. I load images as

```
library(tiff)
img <- readTIFF("someimage.tiff")
```

I'm manipulating with `img` array then and want to see the results. One of the options is use `writeTIFF` function to store the image on the disk and open it with an image viewer. However I wish to have some simple way to display images inside R. What would you recommend?

Comment: From which package comes `readTIFF`? Also, isn't `plot(img)` working?

Comment: Have a look at [`rasterImage`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rasterImage.html)

Comment: @Pascal `readTIFF` comes from `tiff` package. `plot(img)` works... well, sort of. It's not showing the image, but vectors coordinates instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here's one option:

```
img <- readTIFF(system.file("img", "Rlogo.tiff", package="tiff"))
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("someimage.tiff")
plotRGB(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read in the tiff as a native raster, you can use the function `rasterImage()`.

```
 img = readTIFF('someimage.tiff', native=TRUE)
 plot(NA,xlim=c(0,nrow(img)),ylim=c(0,ncol(img)))
 rasterImage(img,0,0,nrow(img),ncol(img))
```

This method works similarly for the functions (and corresponding packages): readJPEG, readTIFF, etc...

Comment: That example does not use any functions from the raster package (I added an answer that does).

Comment: Wow, good catch.  I have edited my answer according to your comment.  Cheers!